# How to avoid a marshal exception

Tags: xml, hibernate, rest, jakarta-ee

I am getting this error

```
The server encountered an internal error (javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked 
exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This 
will cause infinitely deep XML: com.app.Vote@16cc0f7 -> 
com.app.ComplicatedVote@1a961d2 -> com.app.Vote@16cc0f7]) that 
prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

These are the two class (the important parts at least)

**ComplicatedVote.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="complicated-vote")
@Entity
@Table(name="complicated_votes")
public class ComplicatedVote implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity=Vote.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="PARENT_CHILD",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="PARENT_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="CHILD_ID")
    )
    private List<Vote> children = new ArrayList<Vote>();
```

---

**Vote.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="vote")
@Entity
@Table(name="votes")
public class Vote implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="max", nullable=false)
    private int max;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="current", nullable=false)
    private int current;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Column(name="is_simple", nullable=false)
    private int isSimple;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity=ComplicatedVote.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private ComplicatedVote parent;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    @Transient
    private int votedOn;

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity=User.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_VOTES",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "VOTE_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}
    )
    private Set<User> voters = new HashSet<User>();
```

---

Now I am using this with Jax-RS. So the issue only happens when trying to convert it to xml. The logic itself is all working. Problem is I have no idea how to not cause that exception because technically the logic isn't wrong. Or maybe it is. Hoping someone could shed some light on why it does this and how to avoid it. I should also mention that since I am using `@XmlTransient`, this error shouldn't be occurring because it shouldn't be marshaling it I guess. So is there a different annotation I have to use for these type of relationships?

Answer (score 0):

So after a few days of research I finally figured out why it just won't work. I am getting this cyclical error with Jax-rs because it doesn't seem to be something that was ever fixed. Even when adding `@XmlTransient`, it still seems to take into account the entity relationships, like one-to-many in my case. Well this is true with Jboss. I am not too sure if this is something Glassfish was able to fix by default. There are a few tutorials out there that attempt to get around it. I personally thought they were clunky, and thus I just created a separate class (POJO) that existed simply to be converted to xml by Jersey. It works, though I am a little surprised this is even an issue.

Hopefully I'll save some people time when trying to figure out what they did wrong, because its just a bug that can't be fixed. The best you can do is either use the work arounds out on the web or just create a separate class for this purpose.